# JavaScript calculation quarterly billing

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need help to make logic for calculation quarterly billing.

For example: if the owner / tenant enters January, then the bill is for three months until March (January-February-March).
Likewise, if the owner / tenant enters in April, then the billing is for three months until June (April-May-June), and so on.
But, if the owner / tenant enters in February, then the billing is to be prorated 2 months until March (February-March).
Likewise, if the owner / tenant enters in Mei, then the billing is to be prorated 2 months until June (May-June), and so on.
And also, if the owner / tenant enters in March then the billing is to be prorated 1 month only for March.
Likewise, if the owner / tenant enters in June then the billing is to be prorated 1 month only for June, and so on.

Expected results:

If I input January, and the bill is 100000. Then the output is 300000

If I input February, and the bill is 100000. Then the output is 200000

If I input March, and the bill is 100000. Then the output is 100000

Here is my unfinished code so far:

```
const paymentScheme = (month, amount) => {
  const quarterly = [['January', 'February', 'March'],['April', 'May', 'June'],['July', 'Agustus', 'September'],['October', 'November', 'December']];
  const total = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < quarterly.length; i++) {
    total += quarterly[i][1];
  }
console.log(total);
}
paymentScheme('January', 100000)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const paymentScheme = (month, amount) => {
  const quarterly = [
    "January",
    "February",
    "March",
    "April",
    "May",
    "June",
    "July",
    "August",
    "September",
    "October",
    "November",
    "December",
  ];
  const quarter = 3;

  const paymentFactor = quarter - (quarterly.indexOf(month) % quarter);

  const total = paymentFactor * amount;

  console.log(total);
};
paymentScheme("January", 100000);
paymentScheme("February", 100000);
paymentScheme("March", 100000);
paymentScheme("April", 100000);
paymentScheme("May", 100000);
paymentScheme("June", 100000);
paymentScheme("July", 100000);
paymentScheme("August", 100000);
paymentScheme("September", 100000);
paymentScheme("October", 100000);
paymentScheme("November", 100000);
paymentScheme("December", 100000);
```